# Por que compila pero se rompe durante la ejecucion utilizando punteros

Tags: array, c, arraylist, punteros

Compila pero después de capturar los datos el programa se rompe, primero pido los datos al usuario, los guardo y cuando mando a llamar a la funcion es cuando el programa se rompe

```
typedef struct Nodo{
    char *nombre;
    char *mail;
    int edad;
    struct Nodo *next;
}Nodo;


Nodo *crearNuevo(char *nombre, char *mail, int edad){
    Nodo *nuevoNodo;
    nuevoNodo = malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    nuevoNodo->next = NULL;
    nuevoNodo->nombre= nombre;
    nuevoNodo->edad = edad;
    nuevoNodo->mail= mail;
    
    return nuevoNodo;
}Nodo;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! se rompe.. como se rompe? que tipo de error sale?

Comment: Es muy necesario ver qué errores te lanza el compilador, sospecho que tiene que ver con **char *nombre**, yo usaría un array **char nombre[LENGTH + 1]**, con LENGTH de la suficiente longitud con un DEFINE por ejemplo.

Comment: ¿En que parte sale el error? Te recomiendo que uses algún depurador (como `gdb`) para que lance la línea donde ocasione el error (que de seguro es un segment fault).

Comment: El código que adjuntas **compila.**

Comment: @MARS que se haría si no se sabe de que tamaño va ser el nombre?

Comment: @Gabitohh En ese caso debes crear una función tipo [readLine](https://gist.github.com/MrDave1999/09b90de748b9da01490a724aef3df98d) ..

Answer (score 0):

Es muy probable que el fallo esté en los punteros de dentro del Nodo.

Si tu programa hace algo estilo así:

```
char txt[50];

scanf("%s", txt);

crearNuevo(txt, ...);
```

Estás guardando el mismo puntero todo el rato en la variable `nombre` de `Nodo`. Es decir, no importa que nodo estés consultando, si consultas su nombre va a retornar el último que se ha introducido (y si `txt` deja de existir, pongamos porqué la función donde se declaró ha terminado y se destruye la variable, y se consulta un nodo el programa va a crashear).

Haria falta más información, pero si eso es lo que realmente sucede lo que has de hacer es asignar de nuevo la memoria y copiar los datos:

```
Nodo *crearNuevo(char *nombre, char *mail, int edad){
    Nodo *nuevoNodo = NULL; // inicializa a NULL, no todos los compiladores lo hacen

    nuevoNodo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));

    // hay que comprobar si la memoria se ha reservado
    if (nuevoNodo != NULL) {
        nuevoNodo->next = NULL;

        nuevoNodo->nombre = NULL;
        nuevoNodo->nombre = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(nombre) + 1));
        if (nuevoNodo->nombre != NULL) {
            strcpy(nuevoNodo->nombre, nombre);
        }

        nuevoNodo->edad = edad;

        // lo mismo que el nombre
        nuevoNodo->mail = NULL;
        nuevoNodo->mail = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(mail) + 1));
        if (nuevoNodo->mail != NULL) {
            strcpy(nuevoNodo->mail, nombre);
        }
    }
    
    return nuevoNodo;
}Nodo;
```